# Android games that i built don't work on android 4.0.4 because it's not listed in sdk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-tools

I am using `unity3d` for developing games for android and I have a `samsung galaxy s Duos with android v4.0.4`
In fact, this version is not listed in the `android sdk`. so when I ported the apk to this phone, after installing, the game can't open itself ! Note that the problem isn't from the game because i tried it on `kitkat 4.4.2` and `jelly bean 4.1.2` and it works perfectly. What's the solution to run the game on `android 4.0.4 ?`

Comment: Did you take a look at the log? DDMS or Monitor?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain for me more please ?

Comment: check this out http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html

Comment: and how to use it ? it's like android sdk ?